# How can I use std::convert::Into to convert something that might fail?

Tags: rust

I would like a function that accepts a variety of types that can be converted to my specific type. In similar cases, I'd use [`std::convert::Into`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.Into.html#tymethod.into) (or [`std::convert::From`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.From.html)):

```rust
pub struct MyThing;

impl<'a> Into<MyThing> for &'a str {
    fn into(self) -> MyThing { 
        MyThing
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

As an extra wrinkle, in my specific case, the conversion can potentially fail. Normally, I'd use [`Result`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html) to represent an operation that may fail. Combining the two concepts together:

```rust
pub struct MyThing;
pub struct Error;

impl<'a> Into<Result<MyThing, Error>> for &'a str {
    fn into(self) -> Result<MyThing, Error> { 
        if self.len() % 2 == 0 {
            Ok(MyThing)
        } else {
            Err(Error)
        }
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

Unfortunately, this seems to run afoul of coherence rules:

```
error: the impl does not reference any types defined in this crate;
only traits defined in the current crate can be implemented for
arbitrary types [E0117]
```

I see that I could create my own specific trait:

```rust
struct MyThing;
struct Error;

trait IntoMyThing {
    fn into(self) -> Result<MyThing, Error>;
}

impl<'a> IntoMyThing for &'a str {
    fn into(self) -> Result<MyThing, Error> { 
        if self.len() % 2 == 0 {
            Ok(MyThing)
        } else {
            Err(Error)
        }
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

Or even a more-generic trait:

```rust
struct MyThing;
struct Error;

trait MaybeInto<T, E> {
    fn into(self) -> Result<T, E>;
}

impl<'a> MaybeInto<MyThing, Error> for &'a str {
    fn into(self) -> Result<MyThing, Error> { 
        if self.len() % 2 == 0 {
            Ok(MyThing)
        } else {
            Err(Error)
        }
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

But is there any way to reuse components from the standard library to accomplish my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible as-is due to coherence rules, which makes things like this pretty inconvenient, because you can't do it unless you create a newtype for one of the types, either the `Result` or the `&str`. See [RFC #1023](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1023-rebalancing-coherence.md) for more information.

In short, based on the new rules stipulated by that RFC, you cannot implement a trait that's not local to the crate for a type that's not local to the crate.

> 1. Modify the orphan rules so that impls of remote traits require a local type that is either a struct/enum/trait defined in the current crate `LT = LocalTypeConstructor<...>` or a reference to a local type `LT = ... | &LT | &mut LT`.

So since you didn't create the `Into` trait in your crate nor the `Result` type, you get this error. Creating a new type fixes this because it basically wraps a non-local type in a local type.

Comment: Oof! That RFC is a beast and honestly the only thing I took away from it (which is relevant to this question) is that you can't define a trait that is not yours (local to the trait) for a type that's not yours.

Comment: Am I the only one who feels that answers starting with 'nah' are somewhat condescending, or at least a little too informal, no matter how correct its content may be? Also I admit I feel more strongly about this as @shepmaster has helped me more often I can count with highest quality answer that kept their style neutral, preventing oneself from feeling silly for asking.

Comment: That's something that can easily be fixed without needing to accuse me of being condescending, especially when my intention to help (and my answer history) shows that I'm not like that. I mistakenly started my answer casually, where "nah" in this context was meant to convey a feeling of lamentation, as in, "no and it's a shame that this isn't possible." Coherence (the subject of this question) is a source of such feelings in Rust. I don't see what about my answer gives the impression that I was being condescending, or trying to make Shep feel silly for asking.

Comment: Jorge Israel Peña — no worries from my end. I understand that sometimes it's better to add a quick answer out there to get people rolling. I mostly wanted you to add a bit more prose to make the answer better at standing the test of time. @Byron's feelings are still valid though, and it wouldn't surprise me if there were other people that felt similar. It's a good thing for us all to keep in the back of our head!

Comment: Please note that my comment is written to not accuse anyone, it's merely a question asking for feedback as err may well be on my side. The answer has since been edited and to my mind achieved the quality I know from SO. Even though it was left unspoken, I highly value the work of Jorge, who without doubt is a very acclaimed member of this community.